# Property 'push' of undefined - vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, push

I'm trying to get into vue.js a little bit and having some issues with pushing an item to an array. The code below is based of a scrimba tutorial and at first I had elaborated on it a little, but then I got the error: "Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

So I simplified it until I was back at the basics from the tutorial. The error remains though..

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#toDoApp',
    data: {
        todos: [
            { text: 'Learn JavaScript' },
            { text: 'Learn Vue' },
            { text: 'Build something awesome' }
        ]
    }
});

toDoApp.todos.push({ text: 'New item' });
```

After the push statement, the list should be 4 items, rather than the 3 I see.

I've read some things online saying that it is probably because the variable I'm trying to assign it to isn't an array, but as far as I can tell it is. As well as the fact that I can literally find no difference between this and the tutorial code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.todos.push({ text: 'New item' });`

OR

`app.todos.push({ text: 'New item' });`

Comment: So in vue.js "app." equals "this."?

Comment: Your  `let app = new Vue({...})` is creating a `new Vue` instance; thus setting the `new Vue` to the `app` variable.

This is usually the case for any programming language.

You can also check out how it's done here:
https://dev.to/hugoliconv/lets-build-a-todo-app-using-vuejs-52in

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I can see it was late, because I could swear I set the variable to toDoApp, haha.